# CSS nested elements to center

Tags: html, css

Simply i have some `div` on center of page but into this element i can not set center to nested elements. You can see this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zc2ekw85/). In this sample i can not set `table` in center of page. but if I remove `table` and put other element such as `<p>` instead of that, this element is IN center of page.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inside">
        <div class="nested">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        fdfffffffffffffff
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.inside {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.nested{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to center text oinside table?

Comment: @code yes. does not work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox display to center table

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zc2ekw85/1/

```
.container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.inside {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.nested{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your table to `width: 100%;`. The table cell `<td>` will only take up the width of the table and a without specifying a width the table will only be as wide as it's content.

```css
.nested table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zc2ekw85/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
table{ width:100%;}
```

This will set your table text to show in center